# C#: Does passing complicated list of objects to another Class take a lot memory

Tags: c#, memory, command-pattern

This question not directly to mobile application. I needed to create a Command Pattern related structure for Undo and Redo functionality. The Command I will have is AddStrokeCommand, RemoveStrokeCommand and ClearAllCommand. Each of them can be undo.

I will need an Interface say ICommand with Execute and UnExecute.

Example of my code :

```
        public class AddStrokeCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public ObservableCollection <Stroke> Strokes { get; set;}  

        public AddStrokeCommand (ObservableCollection<Stroke> strokes) {
            Strokes = strokes;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Strokes.Add( (Stroke) parameter);
        }

        public void UnExecute()
        {
            Strokes.Remove( (Stroke) parameter); 
        }
    }
```

The application itself is showing many pages which can be annotated, so may have alot of Strokes drawn on each page. If I passed strokes to every command object, will it use a lot of memory? Will there be a better option?

Comment: You are not passing the list, you are simply passing the reference that points to the list.

Comment: Until you know you have a memory problem then you shouldn't worry about it. What you need to do is bit of memory profiling, but my gut feel is that you would be struggling to use any significant amount of memory.

Comment: I think you need to try it and see if there is a problem to solve before you try to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, instances of objects are passed by reference, meaning they do not cause memory to be copied, only a pointer to the memory is passed.

This has the benefit that it does not cost memory usage, also not a high performance hit.

The disadvantage (but can be an advantage too), if you change the passed item, the changes will remain, even after returning to the caller function (because there is only a single instance of the data).

Here you can see more details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: "it will be changed after returning from the called function too" - not terribly clear. It will change the instance is changed - it doesn't have to return first.

Comment: I don't think the change has made it any clearer. You still talk about the the changes remaining **when returning**. The changes are there as soon as they occur.

Comment: I have adapted the text again

Answer (score 1):

Passing a CLASS won't take any significant memory -- ususally just the few bytes used o hold the memory address. It essentially passes an integer which is the position of the object in virtual memory. (Google around for 'pass-by-reference semantics')

A STRUCT is a different matter. A struct is copied every time it's passed into a function or assigned to another variable, so you might find yourself making copies here. See 'pass-by-value semantics' for more.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the following code:

```
var myObject = new SomeVeryBigAndComplexObject();
```

What happens is that you create a new and very big object and store it in some memory previously allocated by the runtime. The *value* stored in `myObject`, if `SomeVeryBigAndComplexObject` is a *reference type* (a `class`), is not the object itself, its simply the memory address of where that object is.

So, when you do any of the following:

```
var obj = myObject;
Foo(myObject);

void Foo(SomeVeryAndComplexObject obj) { ... }
```

What you are really doing is simply copying the *value* stored in the reference `myObj` to `obj`, not the object itself. This is extremely cheap and you shouldn't worry about it at all.

Do bear in mind that all this is true for *reference types*. If the object were a *value type* (a `struct`) then the object itself would be copied because the object itself is the value of the variable `myObject`; that is one of the reasons why structs should always be small objects.